# mapbox - how to set the popup options for a feature layer

Tags: javascript, leaflet, mapbox

I'm using mapbox.js to generate a layer which contains a marker and a popup. I am, at a certain interval, programmatically zooming to that marker and displaying the popup. However, I want to disable the "closeOnClick" functionality of the popup, but if I set it after creating the the featureLayer, it has no effect. Anyone know how to properly do this? Here's my code:

```
eventMarkerLayer = L.mapbox.featureLayer({ //add the event marker
  type: 'Feature',
  geometry: {
      type: 'Point',
      coordinates: [eventPt.lng,eventPt.lat]
  },
  properties: {
    title:eventScenario.text,
    'marker-color': eventColor
  },
  options: {
    popupOptions: {
      closeOnClick: false //doesn't work
    }
  }
}).addTo(map);

eventMarkerLayer.options.popupOptions.closeOnClick = false; //doesn't work either

eventMarkerLayer.openPopup();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Default popup behavior only allows you to open one feature at a time, so you have to add the popups manually using [`L.popup()`](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/api/v2.2.2/l-popup/):

```
eventMarkerLayer = L.mapbox.featureLayer({ //add the event marker
  type: 'Feature',
  geometry: {
      type: 'Point',
      coordinates: [eventPt.lng,eventPt.lat]
  },
  properties: {
    popupContent: eventScenario.text, // note -- change "title" to another name
    'marker-color': eventColor
  }
}).addTo(map);

eventMarkerLayer.eachLayer(function(layer) {
  var popup = L.popup({
      closeOnClick: false, // keeps popups open
      offset: L.point(0, -25) // offset so popup shows up above marker
    })
  .setLatLng([layer.feature.geometry.coordinates[1], layer.feature.geometry.coordinates[0]]) // L.popup takes [lat, lng]
  .setContent(layer.feature.properties.popupContent); // add content from feature
  map.addLayer(popup); // add to map
});
```